# Using array in embedded SQL query in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-datamapper

I have collected ids of a model Student by the following method

```
ids = Student.all.map{|s| s.id}
```

Now I want to use the above array ids in the following sql query in my Ruby code as follows:

```
students = repository.adapter.select(%Q{select id, roll_number, major from students where id in (#{ids})})
```

This above line is giving syntax error because I cannot use ids as an array in this sql query. I am new to Ruby and Mysql. So can anyone give a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
ids = Student.pluck(:id)
repository.adapter.select("some fields").where(["id IN (?)", ids])
```

Comment: It is not working. Could you please give an exact syntax with little example?

Comment: I have just given you an example on how to run query with arrays in rails. I am not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: See I have written the following: ids = Student.all.map{|s| s.id}, pluck is not working however then I written the following statement as you suggested as follows: repository.adapter.select(%Q{select id, name from Students where (["id in (?)",#{ids}])})

Comment: ??could not see your comment

Comment: As I could see Repository has adapter and adapter has student? Are these association there?

Comment: Yes I am selecting from students, the problem is that I cannot use an array directly in a query.